# How to know the time spent for each unit-test case assert statement ONLY

Tags: python, unit-testing, benchmarking

I know there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502516/how-to-know-time-spent-on-each-test-when-using-unittest) already in SO. But my question is different than that.

I am load-testing my script with unit-test. I want to know the time spent for each test-cases *but* which is only running within the `assert` function. Before running the assert my unit-test is doing some work, like generating test-data, loading DB table and other things. I don't want to time those activities. To keep in mind those data-loading is not common for every test-cases, So I can't put that in `setUp` function.

Now let's get into the code -

```
def setUp(self):
    #set up the env

def tearDown(self):
    #tear down everything

def test_fast_case(self):
    #filing up the directories with test data
    self.assertEqual(myscript(param), 1, "Fast!") # I only want the time taken to execute this step

def test_slow_case(self):
    #filing up the directories with test data
    #calling some other function
    self.assertEqual(myscript(param), 100, "Slow!") # I only want the time taken to execute this step
```

Yes! I know there is an easy solution, just to keep a timer before and after the `assert` statement and then print that. But then I have to copy paste 3 lines of code in each of my test function. I am looking for a general and robust solution.

Comment: Why do you want to load-test your app from a unit-test framework? Add metric to your production code - they you will have it available for test and production usage. And you will be able to monitor it in you production environment (machines (which I take is different from the ones running your unit-tests)).

Comment: @Jocke what if I want to load-test my code before pushing it to prod? And let's not get into debate with load-test from unit-test and try to solve the question first.

Comment: Then add it to your pipeline, test in staging (or if possible in some part of the production setup).